# WPF Data Binding Error in ListBox

Tags: wpf, data-binding, binding, listbox, ivalueconverter

I have a `ListBox`:

```
<ListBox x:Name="HistogramListBox" Grid.Column="1" Margin="8,2,8,0"
         HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
         Template="{StaticResource HistogramListBoxControlTemplate}"
         ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource HistogramListBoxItem}"
         ItemTemplate="{DynamicResource BucketTemplate}" />
```

That uses a `DataTemplate` that in turn uses a `ValueConverter` to determine the height of the `ListBoxItem`:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="BucketTemplate">
    <StackPanel>
        <Grid>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="100"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Bottom">
                <Rectangle Grid.Row="0" StrokeThickness="1" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" 
                           Stroke="{Binding ElementName=MainElement, Path=BucketStroke}" 
                           Fill="{Binding ElementName=MainElement, Path=BucketFill}" >
                    <Rectangle.Height>
                        <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource HistogramValueToPercentageConverter}">
                            <Binding Mode="OneWay" Path="ItemCount" />
                            <Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type local:Histogram}}" />
                        </MultiBinding>
                    </Rectangle.Height>
                </Rectangle>
            </StackPanel>
        </Grid>
    </StackPanel>
</DataTemplate>
```

The `ListBox` `ItemsSource` is an `int[]`.

When I execute the code it says it can't find 'ItemCount' on an Int32.  I thought it got the item count from the `ListBox` (I'm obviously wrong).

Can someone tell me how I can get my `ValueConverter` to know what item I am on.

Thanks

Dan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your first converter parameter is intended to be the actual value being charted and the second the Histogram object:

```
<Rectangle.Height>
  <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource HistogramValueToPercentageConverter}">
    <Binding />
    <Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type local:Histogram}}" />
  </MultiBinding>
</Rectangle.Height>
```

This is because the DataContext is the integer itself, at least that appears to be the case from the error message you gave.

By the way, you would normally set the ListBox's ItemsSource using a binding, not from code-behind.  This leads to much cleaner separation of UI and code.  I noticed no `ItemsSource=` was shown in your example code so I thought I should mention this.

Answer (score 1):

The data context of the items in the data template is the data item itself, which is an `int`. If you want to a property on the `ListBox`, you'll need to reach outside of your current context to do so. You can use a `RelativeSource` to do this:

```
{Binding Items.Count, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ListBox}}}
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure ListBox doesn't have an ItemCount property, right?

Comment: @Drew: true. I just copied the OP. Updated my post.

Comment: Items.Count gives me the total number of items. I was looking for the item that it is currently on in the listbox. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can try this for your Binding:

```
<Binding Path="Items.Count">
    <Binding.RelativeSource>
        <RelativeSource AncestorType="{x:Type ListBox}" />
    </Binding.RelativeSource>
</Binding>
```